# How do I set up a Java Apache Derby database in Intellij?

Tags: java, sql, database, intellij-idea, derby

So after many google searches, I still can't figure out how to set up a connectable derby server via Intellij. I do have the Ultimate version, click new project, add a derby remote:

Host: localhost
Port: 1527 (or empty)
Database: same as projectname

And the username and password are usually simple like 'test' on both.
The driver files are installed via Intellij. But when everything is set up and I try to 'Test Connection', I get the following error message:

> Connection to testDB failed
>   java.sql.SQLException: The URL 'jdbc:derby://localhost/testDB' is not properly formed.

Where did I go wrong with this?

Comment: It looks like you don't know the port, database name, or username/password for your database. I'm guessing this because you have the '(or empty)' thing and you say that the username/password are 'usually'. You need to confirm the details, type them into IntelliJ's form, and then it should work fine.

Comment: Perhaps the Derby Network Server is not up and running? Perhaps IntelliJ can't find derbyclient.jar?

Comment: I had to add the "derbyclient.jar" to my Library in the Project stucture menu in Intellij, and start up the "startNetworkServer.bat" file inside the db-folder. That fixed the issues I had connecting to a local database. Sorry for the late answer to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the `derbyclient.jar` to my Library in the Project structure menu in `Intellij`, and start up the `startNetworkServer.bat` file inside the db-folder. That fixed the issues I had connecting to a local database. Sorry for the late answer to this issue

Answer (score 0):

The DB URL pattern should be:

```
jdbc:derby://localhost/testDB
```

or

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:{port}/testDB
```

Comment: The colon shouldn't be in the OP. Edited.

Comment: Actually, Bob.Z, this seems to be an intellij question, and intellij offers exactly that pattern for derby databases and allows construction of it through an interactive form.